# I am trying to delete all the text after a specific character in google sheets. I want to delete from EDP) onwards

Tags: google-sheets

Example:

Guilty Blossoms White (Ladies 200ml EDP)(FP9001)(0015)(2E)

So the result would be:

Guilty Blossoms White (Ladies 200ml EDP)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=regexextract(A1,"[^\)]+\)")
```

[image]

Comment: Absolutely Brilliant, this worked a treat and has saved so much time as I had over 1000 entries to amend.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to delete from EDP) onwards

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1; ".+EDP\)")
```

[image]